# ExactTarget list of unsubscribes this year

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm wondering how to access a unsubscribe list. Usually in a given blast, for ex 250 approx I'll get 3 Unsubscribes. Where can I get a list of all Unsubcribes for this year? is there a place in ET?

I've also looked in ExactTarget Reporting and I looked at the Subscribers drop down from the main menu-- it's not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in a System Data View called [Unsubscribe](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_unsubscribe/), which is accessible via [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).  JobID corresponds to the Job ID in the SFMC user-interface under `Tracking` > `Sends`.

A common process would be:

1. Create a Data Extension with the desired columns.
2. Compose a Query Activity that writes to the Data Extension
3. Create a Data Extract Activity for the Data Extension
4. Create a File Transfer Activity to upload the extracted file to the FTP share
5. Create a Program or Automation that runs steps 1-4.

Comment: hey adam, thank you for your help. I tried the above -- my Extract Type(required) * comes up empty. I create an data extension with SubscriberKey, JobID, EventDate and here is my query: select JobID, SubscriberKey, EventDate from _Unsubscribe where JobID between 10000000 and 150000000. from the query menu I selected a destination from the data extensions where can I see the results?

Answer (score 1):

The results should populate the data extension that you selected and created (which it seems you have).

If you do not see your results being populated, my guess is that your query results are empty. At first pass, I noticed that your JobID range is extremely high and I wonder whether that high range is the cause of your empty results.

You can see a quick snapshot of your jobs and their JobIDs if you go to Tracking > Sends. You should be able to see an overview of your recent email campaign sends and visually see whether your JobID numbers are within range.

Comment: I forgot to "hit" execute()