# Where can you find a list of unsubscribes?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Once someone unsubscribes from a SFMC email where does that information go? I know I can go to All Subscribers and look for the particular individual but how can I just get a list of all the unsubscribes? We have a huge list of contacts (400k +). If I export all our subscribers and then sort it by subscriber status I can extract our unsubscribes, but like I said we have a huge list of contacts. Just exporting all our subscribers takes 20 minutes. Is there any fast, quick way to just look at the unsubscribes?

I have a vendor that needs our unsubscribes weekly. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Adam Spriggs on this post is most likely what you're looking for: [ExactTarget list of unsubscribes this year](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97566/exacttarget-list-of-unsubscribes-this-year)